# In TypeScript, How to define type of method that provide a value returned from member object?

Tags: typescript

```js
interface Foo<T> {
    getValue(): T;
}

class Foo1 implements Foo<string> {
    __value: string;

    constructor(value: string) {
        this.__value = value;
    }

    getValue(): string {
        return this.__value;
    }
}

class Foo2 implements Foo<number>  {
    __value: number;

    constructor(value: number) {
        this.__value = value;
    }

    getValue(): number {
        return this.__value;
    }
}

class Bar<T extends Foo1 | Foo2> {
    private __foo: T;

    constructor(foo: T) {
        this.__foo = foo;
    }

    getValueOfFoo() {
        return this.__foo.getValue();
    }
}

const bar1 = new Bar(new Foo1('hello'));
const val1: string = bar1.getValueOfFoo();

const bar2 = new Bar(new Foo2(12345));
const val2: number = bar2.getValueOfFoo();
```

[Link to TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=46&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0B4AqA%20ZAbwChkzkBzCMANTgBsBXCACgEoAuZHAbmIF9ixBPTgBnMWkwBGZMAC2AB3oR5EcJIzYxYKKAoES5ZAH0TANwbMuOvSAp9S5BOhC3GCMOigtLTCDa6%20mxETsZkYAAWwGIAdGZ%20zMgAvMiJEHzGgmGU1HT%207IF2FKHh5FDUjFAgyFEx8RZWGTmC2SLimpgATHJKKmoaUtggjPIARtAEpeQJTVwj49COxi5uuh5ePunzoxNQIUZltdFxs-4paU2Z5NnGVLRNhcgLe9NlFWBVNXWnjf7XZFaQnaEmQACE4FBcMgIAAPSAgAAmnXQsgAPkMuoYcoo9JZIKYTDBMFxeEIVq53J5vCxiehSQccsYfg06Rc6QDkLdyPd8swAPIwLTsN7hD5fY71Mx02K8x5sTlA4SUsDIMaQ2SpEAQADu4MhLG1eq00hYAHJIhB6PR0Ga2ArlWtLvRpEV9Bd1VBpLK8k1BcKHY6dGrIT0tbr9T4jZiWNIugBmAAsAFZ7XxVsG-F0dosoB7Qz6Hv5-Zh2HwgA)

I expected the return values of 42 and 45 line to be `string` and `number` but they aren't.

How can I define the type of method that can returns proper type depends on object type be provided thru constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why it is currently not working as expected is, that your generic constraint is defined as `T extends Foo1 | Foo2`. Typescript does not allow narrowing of generic unions. See this issue [#13995](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995).

The gist of the issue is this comment from one of the typescript maintainers:

> TL;DR from design discussion: It's somewhat obvious what the "right" thing to do is, but would require a large rework of how we treat type parameters, with concordant negative perf impacts, without a corresponding large positive impact on the actual user-facing behavior side.
>
> If new patterns emerge that make this more frequently problematic, we can take another look.

A quick way to solve your issue at hand is the avoid the generic union like this, not sure if it will fit your actual use case:

```
class Bar<T> {
    private __foo: Foo<T>;

    constructor(foo: Foo<T>) {
        this.__foo = foo;
    }

    getValueOfFoo() {
        return this.__foo.getValue();
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=41&ssc=29&pln=41&pc=21#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0B4AqA+ZAbwChkzkBzCMANTgBsBXCACgEoAuZHAbmIF9ixBPTgBnMWkwBGZMAC2AB3oR5EcJIzYxYKKAoES5ZAH0TANwbMuOvSAp9S5BOhC3GCMOigtLTCDa6+mxETsZkYAAWwGIAdGZ+zMgAvMiJEHzGgmGU1HT+7IF2FKHh5FDUjFAgyFEx8RZWGTmC2SLimpgATHJKKmoaUtggjPIARtAEpeQJTVwj49COxi5uuh5ePunzoxNQIUZltdFxs-4paU2Z5NnGVLRNhcgLe9NlFWBVNXWnjf7XZFaQnaEmQACE4FBcIYcoo9JZIKYTDBMFwtNDls5XO5PN4WCj0GjMNCDjljD8GgSLgSAchbuR7vlmAB5GBadhvcIfL7HepmAmxRmPNi0oHCbFgZBjSGyVIgCAAd3BkJY8qVWmkLAA5JEIPR6OgtWwReK1pd6NIivoLtKoNJBXkmqz2SbTTopZCenLFcqfGqhl0WNIugBmAAsAFZjXxVu6-F0dosoDbPQ6Hv5nZh2HwgA)

Answer (score 0):

I ran the following piece of code (your code) and see the correct result.

```
const bar1 = new Bar(new Foo1('hello'));
const val1: string = <string>bar1.getValueOfFoo();
console.log(typeof(val1))

const bar2 = new Bar(new Foo2(12345));
const val2: number = <number>bar2.getValueOfFoo();
console.log(typeof(val2))
```

Output on console:

```
string
number
```

Comment: In order to remove the warning, do the typecasting on the value you receive. Have updated my asnwer.

Comment: Still does not answer the explicit question asked by the OP: `How can I define the type of method that can returns proper type depends on object type be provided thru constructor?`